# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite Module with non-existent files and no extensions

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I'm using the IIS URL Rewrite module successfully for known file extensions (.aspx, .html, etc.)  However, how can I use the IIS URL Rewrite module for requests with no extensions, or files that do not exist?

For instance:

http://www.example.com/products

should be redirected to a URL in my Rewrite Map.

I've tried putting this in my Rewrite Map but I get a 404.4 "No Handler Specified" error from IIS.

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. The following article details how to handle the exact situation you describe: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/469/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module/